# Some component styles not included in build

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have just noticed that my Vue/Nuxt app is not applying some component styles following build.

The styles are applied as expected in DEVELOPMENT, but once deployed, they don't appear.

Other styles within the component are rendered fine.

**Dev Render:**

[image: Dev Render]

**Prod Render:**

[image: Prod Render]

The styles are applied in the component using the `<style>` tag.

```
<style lang="scss">
    .listing-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;

        @media (min-width: 1024px) {
            grid-template-columns: 50vw 50vw;
        }
    }

    .listing-intro {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 2;

        @media (min-width: 1024px) {
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 2;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 2;
        }
    }

    .listing-map {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        @media (min-width: 1024px) {
            grid-column-start: 2;
            grid-column-end: 3;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 2;
        }

        .explore-map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            > div {
                min-height: 50vh;
                height: auto;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

**The template:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <layout-hero :pageRef="pageContent[0].id"></layout-hero>
        <main class="main listing-page">
            <h1 v-html="pageContent[0].title.rendered + ' around Karratha'"></h1>
            <div class="listing-wrapper" v-if="pageContent[0].id != 68">
                <section v-if="pageContent[0].content.rendered" class="listing-intro listing-content-block" v-html="pageContent[0].content.rendered"></section>
                <section class="listing-map">
                    <layout-map :mapVersion="'activity-map'" :mapCategory="pageContent[0].title.rendered" :zoomVal="7"></layout-map>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <div class="listing-wrapper">
                    <section v-if="pageContent[0].content.rendered" class="listing-intro listing-content-block full-width" v-html="pageContent[0].content.rendered"></section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is it related to the `class` being on the same div as the `v-if`?

Comment: When you check in dev tools, are the **class names** being applied in the right places? That's a good place to start debugging.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Sorry, I should've mentioned, the class names are not rendered on the div in the Production version. They are fine on the Development version. It's like it's not picking them up at all, but it's picking up other styles in the component. I don't understand why it's _partially_ working.

Comment: Does "production" mean "on a production server" or in "production mode" on your local machine? If it's the former, could it be that your code isn't being pushed properly or the old version is just cached in your browser?

Comment: Which styles are not included? Are they related to the grid?

Comment: @Soleno It’s the styles i’ve Included above that aren’t being included. Everything else is, and the same kind of styles are loaded fine on another template.

Comment: @DavidWeldon It’s on a production server. Would changing to production mode make a difference. Is there a way to clear the app cache? I’ve tried clearing the browser one and it doesn’t help. The reason are. O issues in the deployment log that I can see.

Comment: Create a reproduction with your problem on codesandbox

Comment: @Aldarund - how can I when it’s specific to my server and setup?

Comment: So you need to pinpoint what piece of your code create a problem and create a minimal reproduction example where it happens

Comment: @Aldarund The code is exactly the same as code that works elsewhere though...

Answer (score 0):

After stepping away for a day after two weeks of solid work I discovered the issue was due to a style coming through from the map component that was overriding the parent component style.

I am still getting differences between local dev and live production though, even after clearing browser cache and purging the app cache.

UPDATE: The issue was due to `scoped` being included on the map components style block. It is now working as expected.

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: can u brief more spcecific.... i'm curious to know how could you solve this?

Comment: There's not much more I can say. This was over 3 years ago now. I recommend you open a new issue for your specific situation.